# Shopify custom text field print in front-end

Tags: json, shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have added custom text field inside layout header using json :

```
{
        "type": "text",
        "id": "my_text",
        "label": "MyText"
 }
```

Then I have called it inside luquid file like this:

```
{% if settings.my_text%}
              <li class="test">{{ 'layout.header.my_text' }}</li>
{% endif %}
```

In return I'm getting same (layout.header.my_text ) not the value which I added from customizer

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is I changed : layout.header.my_text to settings.my_text .